# Using ejs from js function dosen't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, root, ejs

I created a button in *ejs* file which active a function from a *js* file. 
The function:

```
function signUp(){
    $(`.container`).empty()
    $(`.container`).append("<%- include ('signUp') %>")
}
```

I have a file in the same main *ejs* folder file, which is called "signUp.ejs" that includes a form for signing up .

My problem is that my page just shows :
`<%- include ('signUp') %>` as an html text , and is not showing the content of the *ejs* file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use  `<% include includes/signUp %>` 
If the location of the singUp.ejs is different set it appropriately.

Comment: yea my signUp.ejs file is in the same folder as the main file and i tried "<% include signUp %>", still showing me this as an html regular text on the page

Comment: try <% include ./signUp %>